# VBA sendkeys for Enter button

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, sendkeys

anyone know how to use sendkeys for call enter button in IE11?
already use in some of sendkeys command:

```
SendKeys String:="{Enter}"
SendKeys vbCrLf
Application.OnKey "~"
Application.Sendkeys "{ENTER}"
```

The `Enter` function is still not working.

```
reviews = "ERRORHERE"
On Error Resume Next
reviews = Trim(IE.document.getElementsByClassName("pull-right pagination-page")(0).getElementsByTagName("span")(0).innerText)
On Error GoTo 0
If reviews = "ERRORHERE" Then
    Sheet3.Range("G" & i).Value = "0"
Else            
    Set inputfield = IE.document.getElementsByClassName("pagination-input")
    If inputfield.Length > 0 Then
        inputfield(0).Value = reviews
        inputfield(0).Select
        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
        SendKeys String:="{Enter}" '<< this line for Enter button is not working
    End If
End If
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:2"))
```

Any help with this Sendkeys command? or any help how to use js function instead of vba

Comment: SendKeys vbCr ?

Comment: still the same jim, it's not working

Comment: Why are you using the enter key? Is there a button or something else you could click to achieve the same outcome?

Comment: yes ryan, actually have the arrow button, but i just think if the page will more than 10K, will this make a problem? or make the macro slower?

Comment: okay guys, the problem is fixed, Thank you Ryan, i follow your suggestion using click method, and seem it doesn't make slower the macro, and still wondering, why Sendkeys command is not work